# How can I retrieve full, multi-line Clojure exception content as a string?

Tags: clojure

```
(try
  (/ 1 0)
  (catch Exception e
    (prn e)))
```

prints in REPL as

```
#error {
 :cause Divide by zero
 :via
 [{:type java.lang.ArithmeticException
   :message Divide by zero
   :at [clojure.lang.Numbers divide Numbers.java 158]}]
 :trace
 [[clojure.lang.Numbers divide Numbers.java 158]
  ......................
  [java.lang.Thread run Thread.java 745]]}
```

How to get this complete and comprehensible message with str?

```
(try
  (/ 1 0)
  (catch Exception e
    (str e)))
```

return only

```
=> "java.lang.ArithmeticException: Divide by zero"
```

Comment: Add your solution as an answer (with the "Post Your Answer" button), don't edit it into the question. That way you can accept that answer (thereby marking your question solved) -- and the answer can be voted on, commented on, etc., separately from the question itself.

Comment: thanks for clarification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution is very simple

```
(pr-str e)
```